# Triple boot (2xWindows and Linux)

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

I've got a question. Is it possible to triple boot on a Sony Vaio laptop (VPCF22L1E). I've installed Windows 8.1 Pro after upgrading from Windows 7. Then I installed elementaryOS due to my programming classes and due to that it's cool and really fast. My partition map looks like this:

[image]

I want to install customized [Windows 7 DreamOS](http://winclub.pl/topic/4063-win-dreamos-2015-full-i-lite-pl-en/) (it's modified to increase performance and I think it's the fastest OS I ever come across). It has a special gaming mode, too. The laptop seemed to work flawlessly with Windows 7. SONY officialy stated that the model I've got should not be upgraded to Windows 8 even however they do offer drivers for each module ;).

So my question is:
**Is it possible to install that Windows 7 system on a 63,86GB free space on a logical partition?**
I do not wish to reinstall all systems, which the other guys advised to do in chronological order: Windows 7 first, Windows 8 second, and elementaryOS the third. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to add that further on I will test it by simulation in virtual machine on VirtualBox. Will it resemble the real situation? Of course the disk capacities will be smaller.

Comment: You can install Windows to a logical paritions it just can't be the system partition.since it cannot be activated.  There are tons of instructions on how to get multi-boot systems up and running.  [Here](http://www.pagestart.com/win7heptaboot01.html) is a small explination of the process if you place a logical partition into the mix.  I won't be submitting an answer since there are tons of questions on multi-booting already, and the tutorial I linked to, is something like 9 pages long.

Comment: Thank you, @Ramhound. I just wanted an expert to have a look at my problem and a little tip since I've never multi-booted (only double-boot). I just don't want to screw up anything, because my final exams are getting closer and closer.

Comment: This isn't something you do before final exams.  You need to perform a backup.  Even if you know what your doing you can still choose the wrong option.  Wait until you can afford to make a mistake before you do this.

Comment: OK. Maybe you're right. I just fine computers much more interesting than maths and theories. Thanks again.